# Why doesn't my generic From implementation accept Box<Fn()> values?

Tags: generics, rust, type-conversion, closures, traits

Consider the following simple struct, implementation of `From` for that struct, and function that takes instances of the struct containing boxed functions:

```
struct Foo<T>(T);

impl<T> From<T> for Foo<T> {
    fn from(x: T) -> Self {
        Foo(x)
    }
}

fn call(x: Foo<Box<Fn()>>) {
    let Foo(f) = x;
    f()
}
```

This prints "Hello, world!":

```
call(Foo(Box::new(|| println!("Hello, world!"))))
```

This fails to compile:

```
call(Box::new(|| println!("Hello, world!")).into())
```

The following error message is given:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Foo<Box<std::ops::Fn()>>: std::convert::From<Box<[closure@src/main.rs:15:19: 15:47]>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:15:49
   |
15 |     call(Box::new(|| println!("Hello, world!")).into())
   |                                                 ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<Box<[closure@src/main.rs:15:19: 15:47]>>` is not implemented for `Foo<Box<std::ops::Fn()>>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
   = help:   <Foo<T> as std::convert::From<T>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<Foo<Box<std::ops::Fn()>>>` for `Box<[closure@src/main.rs:15:19: 15:47]>`
```

I can't see any way in which my `From` implementation is any stricter than the `Foo` constructor. Why does `into` fail where `Foo` succeeds here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but I suspect that this won't happen because there are two conversions required, and that's too many jumps to take. Check out the error message again:

```
From<Box<[closure@src/main.rs:15:19: 15:47]>>
```

Note that the error mentions a closure. In Rust, each closure is a unique, un-namable type (sometimes called a [Voldemort type](https://wiki.dlang.org/Voldemort_types)). A closure is **not** a `Fn`, but it does *implement* `Fn`.

For the `From` conversion to work, the starting type would need to be a `Box<Fn()>`. We can see that an explicit cast to `Box<Fn()>` allows it to compile:

```
call((Box::new(|| println!("Hello, world!")) as Box<Fn()>).into());
```

> why isn't the `as Box<Fn()>` needed in my first example using the `Foo` function?

Again, I *suspect* that this works because there's only one conversion taking place. The complier knows how to convert a `Box<closure>` to a `Box<Fn()>` - it's just creating a [boxed trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/trait-objects.html).

I look at it like a little graph. There are two edges:

1. From `Box<closure>` to `Box<Fn()>`. This is provided by the compiler / the `as` keyword.
2. From `T` to `Foo<T>`. This is provided by the `From` implementation.

You can perform the first step (or have it done implicitly), or you can perform the second step via `.into()`. However, there's no step that goes from the very beginning to the very end.

It would probably be a bad idea for the compiler to attempt to traverse the conversion graph to find a conversion path that has arbitrary number of steps. There's also the possibility for there to be many paths, leading to ambiguity.

---

I'd probably write it so that the function takes a generic and does the boxing and conversion itself. This way, the client of `call` doesn't need to deal with those details:

```
fn call<F>(f: F) 
    where F: Fn(),
{
    let x: Foo<_> = Box::new(f).into();
    // I'm assuming something interesting happens
    // here before we unpack the variable again
    let Foo(f) = x;
    f()
}

fn main() {
    call(|| println!("Hello, world!"));
}
```

[Chris Emerson points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581317/why-doesnt-my-generic-from-implementation-accept-boxfn-values/41582037?noredirect=1#comment70390061_41582037) that you can also accept a generic type:

```
fn callg<T:Fn()>(x: Foo<Box<T>>) {
    let Foo(f) = x;
    f()
}

fn main() {
    callg(Box::new(|| println!("Hello, world!")).into());
}
```

This works because we are no longer converting to `Box<Fn()>`, and thus only need one conversion step.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, thanks. But then why isn't the `as Box<Fn()>` needed in my first example using the `Foo` function?

Comment: The `into` version also works if you make `call` generic over any `T:Fn()`:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=85ba2009dac88693b05caa2f5373e975&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: @ChrisEmerson a good point, but it *is* different. In that case, you no longer have a `Box<Fn()>`.

Comment: Agreed.  I haven't got time to go through in detail now, but I think the ["Coercion sites" section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#type-coercions) of the reference is probably relevant.  I think it says that function arguments can be directly coerced (the first case), and the second case doesn't match.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson Thanks, I'll take a look at that section! I need dynamic rather than static dispatch because I'm storing a tree; my actual type looks something like this: `enum Node<T> { Branch(HashMap<String, Node<T>>), Leaf(Bar, T) }`